# Understanding Hadamard gate in depth

Tags: quantum-computing

I know that a Hadamard gate is implemented by rotating around the axis (x + z )/ sqrt(2), but how can I compute the matrix obtained by rotation around this axis by π radians, and compare to a Hadamard gate matrix.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since this is a rotation around Y by 90 degrees and then around X by 180 degrees you should be able to construct the corresponding Y and X rotation matrices and then multiply them.

Comment: Can you add a little details pls? @J.R.

Comment: Maybe search for 'rotation around an arbitrary axis'; basically, you would decompose the rotation steps and then combine the rotation matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Using H = (x + z)/ sqrt(2)

Find the rotation along x-axis (rx), and rotation along z-axis (rz), then multiply.